# Magento Custom Options with stock

Tags: magento

I am developing a vegetable store in Magento. I need a help in this .

"What is the best way to show the vegetable qty as  250gms/500gms/1kg in dropdown."

The main thing here is I need to manage stock also. For example if we sold 500gm qty then the stock decreases by .5 .

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

I think its better if you create a configurable products for this.

you can see more refreance on creating configurable products is :

http://www.sitepoint.com/adding-configurable-products-magento-ecommerce-site/

http://www.magentech.com/documentation/how-to-create-a-configurable-product/

if you want to show 250, 500 & 1000 than give 250gm = 1 quantity, don't give 100 as 1 quantity. because for 250 you can't give 2.5 as quantity.